# Лёгкий скрипт репутации

Tags: php, javascript

Делаю чат для практики и хочу сделать к каждому сообщению счётчик репутации. Если ответ хороший, то пользователь кликает на стрелочку вверх и плюсут балл, нет - наоборот. Лучше было бы, если при плюсовании, каждого сообщения, они бы суммировались и являлись репутацией пользователя. Ну, или, хотя бы, на страничке пользователя обычную голосовалку, только не громозкую, есть такие?

Answer (score 3):

Если напишите, будет. Вы же говорите для ПРАКТИКИ, зачем Вам готовый? Вы бы начали сперва, а затем когда наткнетесь на проблему, спросите. Так проще будет и Вам и тем, кто отвечает.

Чтобы решить эту задачу нужно знать структуру БД. Как пользователь авторизовывается ну и там много чего, о которых только Вы знаете!